# How to calculate the indefinite integral of this function(((1-x)/(1+x))^(1/4))^2

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I calculate the integral of the function below?
I need to calculate the volume of this solid of revolution.
So i need to square the basis function and multiply with $\pi$ in the end.
I've already squared the function, but how do I do the rest?
boundaries: $x\in [0,1]$, solution should be: $\pi(\pi/2 -1)$.

[image: the image]

Comment: try the substitution $x = \frac{2u}{1 + u^2}$

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is [a solid of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution).

Comment: Jyrki, yes, ill change it in the question. ahaan, ive tried to rewrite the part under the root like : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%2F%28x%2B1%29+-1%29       but then im stuck again

Comment: There are probably many substitutions that work. The one proposed by Sonnhard would have been my choice as well (which does not mean that it is the best), because it is the one I'm offering to my analysis/calculus students in their exam "cheat sheets". Can you handle the resulting rational function? The method is standard, but you need to be familiar with a number of steps.

Comment: we have also cheatcheats but that option isnt on it :D and ive succeded to solve it thanks to that substitution.

Comment: Glad to hear that cger! You may consider posting the rest of it: 1) you get some more feedback, 2) you get some upvotes (if mostly correct) - the rep earned may come in handy later, 3) you get an excuse to lear a tiny bit LaTeX. Admittedly doing the steps of such an integration is not the gentlest of introductions to LaTeX, 4) the question will have a full answer as opposed to "just" a useful hint. Your call - no pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with $t=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$ we get $$x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and we obtain
$$dx=\frac{-4t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$ and our integral is given by $$\int\frac{-4t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

Comment: i don't understand this!!!

Comment: +1 for using the substitution in our lecture notes :-)

Comment: did you exspected another substitution?

Comment: No :-) May be somebody else did?

Comment: you are in Finland? wow